# Installation of Python and MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql

On using pip command for installation MySQL connector in python it is giving syntax error

I have tried command:

```
pip install MySQL-connector-python
```

It is showing syntax error.

Comment: Can you add the syntax error to the question?

Comment: >>> pip instal mysql-connector-python
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip instal mysql-connector-python
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I had commented whole on the above comment

Comment: pip install mysql-connector-python, check double L in install

Comment: so what can I change in install as I had used both L and LL

Comment: The prompt you are showing makes it seem like you are running this in a python shell. You should run it in a bash shell or anything similar

Comment: Now it is working for me, can you please write the error you are getting?

Comment: all my efforts are- in next comment

Comment: >>> pip install mysql-connector
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install mysql-connector
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                         "" THIS IS ERROR""

Comment: It is what @user8408080 said, you are inside the python interpreter, you need to put exit() to get out of python interpreter, and then, when you are in you machine terminal, just print the pip install... sentence, it will work :)

Comment: This question should be closed tbh

Comment: @Manuel and it's still showing same error

Answer (score 1):

`>>> pip instal mysql-connector-python` - this `>>>` is python interactive shell.
you must execute `pip` command from command prompt/terminal, e.g. start cmd on Windows and type `pip install mysql-connector-python` on the prompt, e.g.
`c:\>pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: this is most unhelpful comment... it's clear you are doing something wrong and not following my instructions

Comment: please, start giving enough info - what error? eventually show us some screenshot

Comment: C:\Users\HP>pip install mysql-connector-python
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.     """ THIS IS WHAT I DID AND WHAT SYSYTEM SHOWED"""

Comment: This error show that your python installation (and thus pip) is not in system `PATH` variable. i.e. it cannot find your `pip`

Comment: HOW CAN I CHANGE PATH VARIABLE I TRIED MANY TIME VIA ADVANCED SYSTEM SETTING

Comment: if you tried and failed, the best advise is to remove your current python installation and do clean install, following this tutorial https://python-forum.io/Thread-Part-1-Python-3-6-3-7-and-pip-installation-under-Windows VERBATIM

Comment: or read and follow this https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable